# Dynamically removing elements from different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div id='a'>
</div>
....
....
<div id='b'>
</div>
```

combined the script:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'grouplist.php',
    async:false,
    dataType:'json',
    cache:false,
    success:function(result)
    {
        var $ni=$('#a');
        $.each(result,function(key,value)
        {
            var $button=$('<input></input>',{
                'type':'button',
                'id':key,
                'class':'button',
                'value':value
                }).appendTo($ni);
            });
    }});
```

This creates buttons in the `div` with a dynamic id. Now I am dynamically adding elements into `div` with id b if I click on one of these buttons as follows:

```
$('#a').on('click','.button',function(){
    $('.hmm').remove();
    var x=$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'groupmsg.php',
        async:false,
        data:'id='+x,
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
        success:function(result)
        {
            var $na=$('#groups');
            $.each(result,function(key,value)
            {
                var t_msg=value[0]+":"+value[1]+"\t"+value[2];
                var $p = $('<p></p>'{'id':'msg'+key,'class':'.hmm'}).html(t_msg).prependTo($na);
            });
            }
            });});
```

I am unable to remove the elements of `div#b` using `$('.hmm').remove();`. Can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: does $('#a').on('click','.button',function(){} works at all? [you can check this by replacing the content of the function with a simple alert("!") ]

Comment: I don't know it helps, but I think you have a syntax error here: `var $p = $('<p></p>'{'id'` : a comma is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code, should be:

```
var $p = $('<p></p>',{'id':'msg'+key,'class':'hmm'})
```

No dot (.) should be used when setting class.

Comment: @charlietfl  ok, i see what you mean now

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are attaching `click` event to the div with `id=a` and clicking on button which is created inside another element. Try to attach `click` event to document instead.

```
$(document).on('click','.button',function(){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Anyway you should fix your code like is said in another answer and see if it works.